# Troubleshooting FirebaseError: Expected type '_h', but it was: a custom FirestoreQuery object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
export default function Todo() {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { user } = useAuth();

    const query = firestore()
        .collection("todos")
        .where("userId", "==", user?.uid)
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc");

    const [data, loading] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: "id" });

    const handleDelete = item => e => {
        Alert.alert('Delete Confirmation', 'Are you sure want to delete this todo?', [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => { },
                style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
                text: 'Yes', onPress: async () => {

                    await firestore().collection("todos").doc(item.id).delete();

                }
            },
        ]);

    }



    return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    
        <Appbar>
            <Appbar.Content title="Your To-do" />
        </Appbar>
        
        {loading ?
            <View style={styles.loading}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
            :
        
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    const { title, description } = item;
                    return <List.Item
                        left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="checkbox-blank-circle" />}
                        title={title}
                        description={description}
                        right={props => <View {...props}>
                            <View style={styles.actionBtns}>
                                <IconButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ToDoForm", {
                                    mode: "update",
                                    item
                                })} icon="pencil" />
                                <IconButton
                                    onPress={handleDelete(item)}
                                    icon="delete" />
                            
                            </View>
                        </View>}
                    />
                }}
            />} 


        <FAB
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ToDoForm", { mode: "create" })}
            style={styles.fab}
            icon={"plus"}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>

}
```

I tried to make a to-do list using react native firebase with the above code. It defines a Firestore query to retrieve the to-do items associated with the currently logged-in user. The query filters the todos collection based on the userId field and orders the results by createdAt in descending order.The useCollectionData hook is used to subscribe to the Firestore query and retrieve the data. It returns the data and a loading indicator.The handleDelete function is defined to handle the deletion of a to-do item. It displays an alert to confirm the deletion and, upon confirmation, deletes the item from Firestore. But I get this error message

```
 FirebaseError: Expected type '_h', but it was: a custom FirestoreQuery object
```

Any suggestion?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct to me. Can you verify if the item.id is defined and also update the handleDelete to something like this?

```
    const handleDelete = item => {
        console.log(item.id); // Check item.id value

        Alert.alert('Delete Confirmation', 'Are you sure want to delete this todo?', [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => { },
                style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
                text: 'Yes', onPress: async () => {
                    if (item.id)
                       await firestore().collection("todos").doc(item.id).delete();
                }
            },
        ]);

    }
```

Then update the button component

```
<IconButton
  onPress={() => handleDelete(item)}
  icon="delete" 
/>
```